# WaitForSingleObject while debugging (General slowness during debugging)

Tags: multithreading, delphi, winapi

I must say I know a lot of things about threads, but theres something that is driving me crazy.

I use to wait for a thread using the Windows API function `WaitForSingleObject` and it works fine. But, when i am debugging my code, it seems that `WaitForSingleObject` is very, very, very slow (it hangs a lot). But when I am just running my app without debug, `WaitForSingleObject` is very, very fast.

Why does this happen? Is it because of Messages that the IDE sends? Or is it because of the compiler?

This is not affecting me a lot. I just think this issue is really annoying.

Edit: I am using Delphi 2010.

Comment: WaitForSingleObject runs at the same speed no matter whether you are debugging or not. What you are probably observing is that some of your threads are frozen. Multi-threaded debugging can be a little fragile.

Comment: Everything is slower while debugging even if you have a single thread. More threads means yet more waiting. I would say there's no way out with this issue. IMHO there are no settings in IDE to speed up this case.

Comment: How slow is "very, very, very slow"? Can you post your code? I can't think of any reason the function itself would be slower while debugging. Could it be a debugger artefact (e.g. in .NET, suspending a thread takes a non-trivial amount of time. If your process has many threads, the debugger has to resume and suspend all of them every time you single-step, which can take some time - I've seen 1-2 seconds on occasion.)

Comment: @daemon_x could you explain how calling kernel32.WaitForSingleObject would be slower whilst debugging?

Comment: @david Sorry, but I disagree. I can see that WaitForSingleObject is slow when debugging. Thats not a thing I am not sure of.

Comment: @telewin Very slow means 10 seconds slower when debugging. I am sorry, but I cant post my code here because its far complicated. I only have 1 thread (and the main thread of course).

Comment: @David Heffernan - the function itself as the rest of the core functions and messages are processed by the kernel with the same speed. But the debugger messages capture slow down the debug process.

Comment: @Rafael How can that function be slow? Presumably the delay is in whatever it is waiting for!

Comment: @daemon_x debugger messages capture? What's that? I'm probably being a bit dim.

Comment: @David Heffernan - something described here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679302%28v=VS.85%29.aspx, well, I feel you want to tell me, that the application executed through the debugger and from the explorer will run the same speed. They'll never do ...

Comment: @daemon_x My app performs just the same whether or not a debugger is attached. I guess it must be doing something different from your app.

Comment: Rafael : What version of windows are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really doubt that WaitForSingleObject is in fact the ONLY thing that gets slower. Rather, it is probable that almost everything gets slower, when you run with debugging on.

I find that far more than Win32 API calls, calls to OutputdebugString slow me down, and anything that the IDE chooses to log in the event view, really, because a big load of these event or output messages, slows the IDE, the debugger, and thus the program that I'm debugging, a lot.

Try turning off the event view checkboxes in the configuration menu and see if EVERYTHING gets faster.

It's in Tools -> Options, as shown by the OP in his image, which I've also added here, for handy access:
[image]

Comment: isn't that means "add more ram" ?

Comment: @cpprogrammer, no it is not. No mather how much memory you have, debugging is going to be slower than not debugging if you dont do what Warren P said. Maybe this is why you are getting downvoted. You should consider deleting you answer (maybe you can get a new badge :) )

Comment: I have deleted my answer since you got my screenshot.

Answer (score -4):

Add more ram :) you probably have a not so powerful machine. I had a similar problem but using vs2010. Anyway the principles are the same: Running in debug mode adds an overhead from the  checks added by compiler to the code and move overhead from the environment itself that must manages threads, resources and stuff for the case you want to see them.

PS: What makes you think the problem are the Wait* functions ? Have you made a simple application that use Wait* and behaves the same ?

Comment: Lol. I am running Delphi in a Intel Core I7 machine with 8GB RAM DDR3 1333

Comment: should be enough :P. Then try to reproduce but in a smaller application and contact Delphi.

Comment: It is a wait issue, thats i am sure. I am working on a simple app right now, but it can take some time since I am full of work today.

Comment: As a second thought you can avoid that. Case A) The problem is with Delphi -> you are not alone -> go to forum.  Case B) try to be sure that Wait* functions are your problem, like logging before entering Wait* and compare timestamps and reason of exit (should be WAIT_OBJECT_0)

Comment: please comment a negative grade

Comment: The negative votes  are because your answer is totally wrong and not applicable to this question. (I would think someone posting as "cprogrammer" would have know better.) You might want to delete your answer before you lose any more rep.

Comment: i have never used Delphi, but I have shared my experience with vs2010. if you want to work in a solution with more than 100 projects you'll see that 4Gb are not enough. Even if the answer is incorrect - "8Gb of ram should be enough for anybody :), the idea is valid, not totally wrong. Debugging is an overhead. From start (code) to the end (ide). I have asked for comment because i'm interested in feed back more than I am interested for a badge or rep. I Hope you have understand my request now.